# ActiveRecord Rails: Query "where" combine different conditions

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I am doing a search filter and looking for a method to combine different conditions in a query where statement as following:
the query should show either (1) all visits with symbol "AATR" or (2) all visits with symbol "ACCT" or (3) all patients with screening id in an array_ids_scr or (4) all patients with study id in an array_ids_std.
I know how to write each statement individually but i do not know how to combine them.
Individually, it should be

```
where("visits.symbol = 'AATR' OR visits.symbol = 'ACCT'")
where("patients.scr_id IN (?)", array_ids_scr)
where("patients.std_id IN (?)", array_ids_std)
```

I tried to combine them as following but it did not work (syntax error at or near)

```
where("
visits.symbol = 'AATR'
OR
visits.symbol = 'ACCT'
OR
patients.scr_id IN #{array_ids_scr}
OR
patients.std_id IN #{array_ids_std}
")
```

Is there a way to do that? I am using rails 6.

Comment: Thanks I tried doing so, but still received PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" LINE 261

which better ways exist. would you please advise

Comment: `where('..... OR patients.scr_id (?) OR patients.std_id IN (?)', array_ids_scr, array_ids_std)`?

Comment: You might want to put your answer as an Answer, @razvans, so that you can get it accepted.

Comment: @JohnP Thanks. I forgot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `IN` the resulting query should look like `.. IN (1,2,3)`. The way you have it there it looks like `...IN [1,2,3]`. For this it's best to leave ActiveRecord handle the query params by using `?`.

> Active Record will take the first argument as the conditions string and any additional arguments will replace the question marks (?) in it.

```
where("
 visits.symbol = 'AATR' OR 
 visits.symbol = 'ACCT' OR
 patients.scr_id IN (?) OR 
 patients.std_id IN (?)", array_ids_scr, array_ids_std)
```

You can read more in the docs, [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions)